# Replace and Keep Some part of the string in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I do following in Node js/Javascript?

Eg. Say original occurence = "xyz-abc-def"
I wanted to replace whole occurrences of above string by "123-abc-456". xyz and def are constant in above string while abc can be any string in original occurence. Eg.

```
"xyz-asd-def" -> "123-asd-456"
"xyz-ghj-def" -> "123-ghj-456"
```

How can I do that in node js?

Comment: While asking questions on SO is a real good way to solve problems, i would recommend you to have a deeper regex tutorial first, this is quite a simple problem for regexers

Comment: Is it safe to assume "xyz" and "def" are unique across the entire string? Also, how many occurrences would you expect in a single string? Finally, what have you actually tried? Show your work.

Comment: @James you are right. I actually have no idea on how to do this and I am not sure what to search for this kind of case online also. Actually, I am very new to Node js and javascript. I am writing my first script today.

Comment: "abc can be any string" does it mean it can include special character?

Comment: @kgangadhar yes it can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a regular expression.

```
var reg = /xyz-(.+?)-def/g;
var input = 'xyz-asd-def';
var result = input.replace(reg, '123-$1-456');
```

Comment: Yeah you can, but this solution is brittle - try this with "xyz-asd-def xyz-dsa-def", or any other variation of the string where it contains more than one pattern. It might not be important but it's important to explain the limitations of your solution.

Comment: @James You're right, in that case the greedy regular expression would fail. This behaviour can be changed easily by making it lazy, and the use-case for this is what decides what way it should behave. I have updated my answer to use a lazy regex, as that seems more suitable for the problem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to replace all instances of each text string you're trying to replace.

```
"def-xyz-asd-def"
    .replace(new RegExp("xyz","g"), "123")
    .replace(new RegExp("def","g"), "456");
```

Will result in "456-123-asd-456"

Answer (score 0):

Based on the intricacies of your requirements, the best route would be a [Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

You can use a capture group to extract only the parts of the string you need and, given your patterns are constant, you can rebuild the string e.g.

```
"xyz-asd-def".replace(/xyz-(\S+)-def/, "123-$1-456");
```

This will capture any non-whitespace characters inside the pattern of "xyz-xxx-def" with no length restriction. If you expect to have multiple instances of this pattern in a single string, use the global replace option (append g to the end of the regex)